# Dynamically add AzureAD users to AzureAD group in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I recently started working with terraform and am currently working on adding people to groups for access management. I've got a bunch of `user_principal_names`, basically unique identifiers within AzureAD, of people that are already added to AzureAD. I now need to add these people to `azuread_group` objects. I've got it working by requesting each person's `azuread_user` object in the top of my `main.tf` file, and then adding them to groups. This isn't a really scalable solution however, and I was wondering if there is a more dynamic method, can I for example work with an array containing these `user_principal_name` objects? Or do I always first have individually get each `azuread_user` object?

```
data "azuread_user" "jack" {
  user_principal_name = "JackDoe@Company.Com"
}
data "azuread_user" "john" {
  user_principal_name = "JohnDoe@Company.Com"
}

resource "azuread_group" "admins" {
  display_name = "admins"
  owners = [
    data.azuread_user.jack.object_id,
  ]
  security_enabled        = true
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  members = [
    data.azuread_user.john.object_id,
  ]
}
```

This is an example of how I've got it working right now.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each.

Comment: Sorry for a non-terraform solution. We had similar problems in our projects, if you have `Azure AD premium P1 license`, I highly recommend you to use [dynamic-ad-groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-create-rule) feature on Azure. It just scales the way you define with rules & no need to run terraform on each user/sp creation. 

If it doesn't work, you can write few crons to periodically check for new users/sps & add to groups..

Answer (score 0):

main.tf:

```
data "azuread_users" "users" {
  ignore_missing       = false
  user_principal_names = var.ad_users
}

resource "azuread_group" "ad_group" {
  display_name     = "New_AD_Group"
  security_enabled = true
  members          = data.azuread_users.users.object_ids
}
```

terraform.tfvars.json:

```
{
  "ad_users": [
    "user_1@domain.com",
    "user_2@domain.com"
  ]
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "ad_users" {
  type = list(any)
}
```

Also, here could be more complex solution for variable construction like:

```
{
  "assignments": {
    "AD_GROUP_1": {
      "users": [
        "user_1@domain.com",
        "user_2@domain.com"
      ]
    },
    "AD_GROUP_2": {
      "users": [
        "user_3@domain.com",
        "user_4@domain.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For this way you have to use `for_each`